# $|f(x)-f(y)| = 2 |x - y| $, find such functions

Tags: functions, solution-verification

> Find all the functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$|f(x)-f(y)| = 2 |x - y| $$

---

My attempt: using the condition given in the problem, for some real $c$, $$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = \lim_{x\to c}\frac{\pm 2|x-c|}{x-c}= \pm 2$$ hence the limit exists and is finite and either $+2$, or $-2$. Hence the derivative at $c$ exists, as $c$ was an arbitrary real, hence the function is differentiable everywhere with the derivative either positive or negative $2$, which gives $f(x)=2x+c, -2x+c$ as our answer.

**Primary concern** is regarding the existence of derivative part. Have I proved the existence correctly (i.e. have I shown the existence of limit correctly). Also I know that limit must be unique, but here I'm getting 2 limits. How would that be possible?

Comment: The `solution-verification` tag requires that you explicitly identify a step  in your argument that you are unsure about, and to explain why you are unsure about. The site does not function as a 'here's-my-proof-please-check-it-for-me' site.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin should I change the tag in this case, as I don't know what might be wrong with this proof? As I said, my suspicion about it's validity solely came from the fact that my book had a different and rather complicated solution, and not something inherently from this solution itself.

Comment: And as I said, we are not a "Here's my proof, check it in its entirety for me" site. The tag simply informs you of what you need to do in order for your post to be on-topic. If you have no doubts about your arguments, then you are in the wrong place.

Comment: @Aruralreader the derivative, if exists, would be constant, either +2, or -2

Comment: Your solution is wrong. The sign can change as $x\to c$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin fair, let me rephrase and edit the post

Comment: I will note that your first limit equality is unjustified. You know that for each $x$, $f(x)-f(c)$ equals either $2(x-c)$ or $-2(x-c)$; but you don't know which, and you do not know that if $x$ changes you will get the same sign. So you "really" have something like $|f(x)-f(c)| = (-1)^{g(x)}2|x-c|$, where $g(x)$ is a function that takes the value $0$ or $1$ depending on the sign.

Comment: Various solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2282818/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't prove that the derivative exists. You're right that $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = \frac{\pm 2|x-c|}{x-c}$ but the sign depends on $x$ and $c$. *If* the derivative exists then it must be equal to $2$ or $-2$, but your approach doesn't show that it exists.

---

By subtracting $f(0)$ from $f$, we can assume $f(0) = 0$. We have $|f(x)| = 2|x|$ so that $f(x) = \alpha(x)\cdot 2x$ for some function $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\{-1, 1\}$.

We have $| \alpha(x)\cdot x - \alpha(y)\cdot y| = |x-y|$. If $x>y>0$ then we get $x-y = x - \alpha(x)\alpha(y)y$, that is $\alpha(x)\alpha(y) = 1$, so $\alpha(x) = \alpha(y)$. Similarly if $x < y < 0$. Thus $\alpha$ is constant on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$.

This implies that $f(x) = 2|x|$ or $f(x) = -2|x|$ or $f(x) = 2x$ or $f(x) = -2x$. Of course, only the last two possibilities work. Considering that we've removed $f(0)$ in the beginning, solutions are $f(x) = \pm 2x+C$ for $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so what it really means is that, while $|f(x)=2|x|$, the function itself might "jump" on either +2 or -2 here and there depending on $x$, making the function discontinuous right? So, if I prove the function is continuous (which is possible with the given condition), my solution would be correct (i.e. the derivative argument)

Comment: You could argue that if we had $f(x) = 2x$ and $f(y) = -2y$ for some $x, y > 0$ then $f$ won't be continuous on $(0, \infty)$, which is impossible. Similarly for $x, y < 0$. Then it this will imply that $f(x)$ has constant sign on the positive and negative numbers, and you can use the derivative trick there... but the derivative trick is kind of irrelevant since we already know that $f(x) = \pm 2x$ for $x > 0$ (or $x < 0$).